# I need to make an "onclick" 'loading page' while next page works

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a form that submits to a next page.

Currently this next page executes several commands before it is ready to load the page.

What happens now:
Form is submitted with Get or Post
nothing happens for many many seconds . The impression is that the page is hung. 
The next page is displayed only once a series of events occurs (in this case creating a PDF with imagemagick) finally the next page loads only after all the execution.
I did try adding some javascript to show a "loading" message on this next page that works but ONLY after the PDF is created. It does not overcome the "hung" appearance. For reasons I can not go into here scripting the commands is not an option, tried that.

What I want:
I am no javascript guru so forgive me for that, but I believe I can create an onclick event that *while still submitting the form* (and this is important) shows a "loading" message? Meaning clicking submit still fires the traditional next page but javascript fu will cause a "loading" message to appear , preferrably overlayed. Of course once the next page loads this overlaid message will now go away.

I have seen some solutions for doing this kind of thing but never a javascript message WHILE still submitting the form

In short, I want my existing submit button to still work as it does now, but the button needs to fire off a second function of unhiding the "loading" message

Thanks in advance if anyone can show me an example of how to do this.

I tried this but as I said no javascript guru. I cobbled it to gether from other places and what I found, but does not work.

The message

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none;>
    <table border=0 style="width: 30%"><tr><td><hr></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="color:#666; font-weight:bold"><br/><br/>Please wait , Thinking...</span></br></br><br/>
    <img src="../images/spinner.gif"></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

The button

```
<button id="makemppdfnow" onclick="javascript:loadingWait();" style="float: left; height: 36px; background-image: url(images/makepdf btn.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: left;padding left: 39px; color:#666; font-weight:bold" type="submit" formaction="/mkmppdf.php">'.$makepdf.'</button>
```

Javascript

```
function loadingWait() {
    if (document.getElementById('makemppdfnow').click) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
```

Comment: You should tell the user that that somethig is happening as soon as they perform an action, e.g clicking your button - make a loading graphic appear as soon as they click the button. _"I did try adding some javascript to show a "loading" message on this next page that works but ONLY after the PDF is created."_

Comment: @Stuart yes I agree but as I stated I need this to come from the page where the submission is made not the subsequent page. That does not avoid the delay.

Comment: So you trigger "it" as they submit the form right..

Comment: that is the idea @Stuart

Answer (score 0):

**you forgot a close Bracket.**

I think you should do this:

onclick="loadingWait()"

instead of this:

onclick="javascript:loadingWait();"

tell me if it solved the problem.

Comment: No, it does not. I also found missing clode bracket in Javascript as posted here . Not sure if it needs something after the curly bracket

Comment: function loadingWait() {
    if (document.getElementById('makemppdfnow').click) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

and then :

onclick="loadingWait()"

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about why the 'loading' div doesn't show up, then please find the script below and make the changes accordingly. You have set the display:none to the 'loading' div, so you have to make change to the style of display instead of changing the visibility.

```
<script>
boolean =false;
function loadingWait() {
boolean = true;

if(boolean ==true){
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
                  } 
else {
       document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
       boolean = false;
     }
    }
    </script>
```

And do change the onclick="javascript:loadingWait();" to onclick="loadingWait();"